# Pass function as function parameter to order linked list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing a program that provides the tools to create and manipulate a linked list. I've already finished the methods to add, delete nodes, etc. However, in order to create the method that orders the list, my teacher has asked me to make it with a function that receives another function as a parameter. I think the logic I used works well, however, it doesn't seem to work when calling the method from main. Here's the method:

```
...
int comparador(T valor1, T valor2){
    if(valor1>valor2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(valor1<valor2){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

void ordenar(auto comparador(T,T)){
    if(this->tam <= 1){
        return;
    }
    for(Nodo<T>* i = this->cabeza ; i != NULL; i = i->siguiente){
        for(Nodo<T>* j = i->siguiente; j != NULL; j = j->siguiente){
            if(comparador(i->valor, j->valor)==1){
                T temporal = i->valor;
                i->valor = j->valor;
                j->valor = temporal;
            }
        }
    }

}
...
```

Edit: Updated the compiler to C++ 20. These are the new errors:

```
====================[ Build | untitled34 | Debug ]==============================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\juanf\CLionProjects\untitled34\cmake-build-debug --target untitled34 -j 10
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled34.dir/main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/untitled34.dir/main.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE   -g -std=gnu++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/untitled34.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\untitled34.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/untitled34.dir/main.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp
C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp:131:21: error: no matching function for call to 'Lista<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::ordenar(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
  131 |     mi_lista.ordenar(mi_lista.comparador);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp:100:10: note: candidate: 'template<class auto:16> void Lista<T>::ordenar(auto:16 (*)(T, T)) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
  100 |     void ordenar(auto comparador(T,T)){
      |          ^~~~~~~
C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp:100:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp:131:21: note:   mismatched types 'auto:16 (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)' and 'int (Lista<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)'
  131 |     mi_lista.ordenar(mi_lista.comparador);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/juanf/CLionProjects/untitled34/main.cpp:131:21: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto:16'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

[In image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I6z9.png)

This is the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename  T>
struct Nodo{
T valor;
Nodo<T>* siguiente;
Nodo(T valor){
    this->valor = valor;
    this->siguiente = NULL;
}
};

template<typename T>
struct Lista{
Nodo<T>* cabeza;
Nodo<T>* cola;
int tam;
Lista(){
    this->cabeza = NULL;
    this->cola = NULL;
    this->tam = 0;
}

bool esta_vacia(){
    return this->cabeza == NULL && this->cola == NULL;
}

void agregar_nodo(T valor){
    Nodo<T>* nuevo_nodo = new Nodo<T>(valor);
    if(this->esta_vacia()){
        this->cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
        this->cola = nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        this->cola->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
        this->cola = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    this->tam= tam++;
}

void imprimir_lista(){
    cout << "Valores de la lista:" <<endl;
    for(Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza ; itr != NULL; itr = itr->siguiente){
        cout << itr->valor << endl;
    }
}
void insertarEnPos(int pos, T valor){
    Nodo<T>* nuevo_nodo = new Nodo<T>(valor);
    if(pos == 0){
        nuevo_nodo->siguiente = this->cabeza;
        this->cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    else if(pos == this->tam-1){
        this->cola->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
        this->cola = nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza;
        for(int cnt=0 ; cnt < pos-1; itr = itr->siguiente,cnt++){}
        nuevo_nodo->siguiente = itr->siguiente;
        itr->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    this->tam= tam++;
}

void actualizarPos(int pos, T nuevoValor){
    Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza;
    for(int cnt=0; cnt<pos; itr = itr->siguiente, cnt++){
        if(cnt==pos-1){
            itr->siguiente->valor=nuevoValor;
        }
    }
}

void eliminarElemento(int pos){
    Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza;
    for(int cnt=0; cnt<pos || (cnt==0&&pos==0); itr = itr->siguiente, cnt++){
        if(cnt==pos-1){
            itr->siguiente=itr->siguiente->siguiente;
        }
        if(cnt==0&&pos==0){
            this->cabeza=itr->siguiente;
        }
    }
}

int comparador(T valor1, T valor2){
    if(valor1>valor2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(valor1<valor2){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

void ordenar(auto comparador(T,T)){
    if(this->tam <= 1){
        return;
    }
    for(Nodo<T>* i = this->cabeza ; i != NULL; i = i->siguiente){
        for(Nodo<T>* j = i->siguiente; j != NULL; j = j->siguiente){
            if(comparador(i->valor, j->valor)==1){
                T temporal = i->valor;
                i->valor = j->valor;
                j->valor = temporal;
            }
        }
    }

}
};
int main()
{
    Lista<string> mi_lista;
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("1 asd asd");
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("2");
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("10");
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("-568");
    mi_lista.insertarEnPos(2,"lk");
    mi_lista.actualizarPos(2, "miau");
    mi_lista.imprimir_lista();
    cout<<"========================\nCon nodo eliminado:\n===================\n";
    mi_lista.eliminarElemento(4);
    mi_lista.imprimir_lista();
    cout<<"========================\nOrdenando:\n===================\n";
    mi_lista.ordenar(mi_lista.comparador);
    return 0;
}
```

I must clarify that the teacher told me to use "auto" data type for the function passed as a parameter in the order metod. I've tried using pointers, but nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++20`?

Comment: Did you read the error message and add `-std=c++20` to your compile command?

Comment: @Eljay where can I put that?. Edit: Done, still doesn't work. I keep getting "no matching function for call to..."

Comment: @RetiredNinja where can I put that?. Edit: Done, still doesn't work. I keep getting "no matching function for call to..."

Comment: It would be best to remove the snippet at the top of your question, add the `main` function you are using to the code at the bottom, and add the text of the errors to the question instead of an image. Adding the switch for c++20 alone won't fix the issue but once you've added it you'll be asking the right question.

Comment: You probably want `this->tam++;` instead of `this->tam= tam++;` in the `agregar_nodo` function. You also don't need to use `this->` everywhere, it just adds noise to the code. You would need it if you had a function parameter with the same name as a member variable but it is best to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: FYI, there is a function `std::swap` you should become familiar with.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews As I'm in college, I'm not allowed to use it yet.

Comment: @JuanFelipeRubiano That is a weird college requirement.

Comment: @user12002570 I mean, I think they do it so we know how a button works before pressing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lista<string>::comparador` is not a function, it is a non-static member function.  Those are very different things.

Your `Lista<string>::ordenar` member function expects a function that accepts two `string`s, but `Lista<string>::comparador` isn't that.  It accepts two `strings` **and a `Lista<string>` object**.  The two types are simply incompatible.

The simplest way to fix that problem is to either make `comparador` `static` or move it out of your `Lista` class template and make it a freestanding function.

Comment: Moving it out of the function worked perfect. Thank you!